# Selenium - 'site' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_link_text'

Tags: python, selenium, attributeerror

I'm trying to write a python script that clicks a certain link in a table on a webpage. The only option I have to select this particular link is it's link text, but selenium keeps telling me that the command "find_element_by_link_text" doesn't exist even though it's found on not only the official selenium docs but also multiple online selenium examples. Here's the code snippet:

```
hac.find_element_by_link_text("View this year's Report Cards").click()
```

I cross-checked my selenium installation with one from the website and they seem to be the same. Was this feature deprecated or am I just missing something? I'm using selenium v.2.45.0 and python v.2.7.

Comment: If you post some of your script and a link to the page you are trying to access, I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `find_element_by_link_text()` method using `driver`.

Here is a sample script that opens the Python home page, locates the link to the About page using its link text, and then clicks that link:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("About")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elem.click()
```

This page of the Selenium [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) gives an overview of all of the `find_element` methods available, and shows how to call those methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python selenium 4.3 some methods are deprecated like

```
find_element_*() and find_elements_*()
```

Examples:

```
find_element("name","element_name")
find_element("xpath","xpath_here")
```